# coordinate ring of curve

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Assume one has a curve $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^2(k)$ defined by a polynomial in $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$. By intersecting it with the hyperplanes defined by $x_0 \neq 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$ one obtains an affine open cover of it which consists of two affine curves, in this case the zero sets $Z(y^n-x^{n-1}+1)$ and $Z(v^n-u+u^n)$ respectively. I think these have coordinate rings given by $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^n-x^{n-1}+1)$ when $x_0 \neq 0$ and $\mathbb{C}[u,v]/(v^n-u+u^n)$ when $x_2 \neq 0$ respectively. How can I find the coordinate ring of the intersection of these affine curves, i.e. when I impose both $x_0$ and $x_2$ to be non zero?

Comment: When you say hyperplanes, do you mean affine planes?

Comment: So the polynomial ought to be something like $x_1^n-x_2^{n-1}x_0+x_0^n$ right?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the affine plane $x_0\ne 0$, $\Bbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$ the curve is given by $x_1^n-x_2^{n-1}+1$, to impose $x_2\ne 0$, we just localize at $x_2$ to get that the intersection has coordinate ring $\Bbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_2^{-1}]/(x_1^n-x_2^{n-1}+1)$. 
Alternatively in the other open affine $x_2\ne 0$, it has coordinate ring $\Bbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_0^{-1}]/(x_1^n-x_0+x_0^n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not too familiar with localisation. Why does localising yield the intersection's coordinate ring?

Comment: Well, if I declare $x_2$ to be invertible, then it can't be 0. I'm honestly not sure how to even begin to explain that.

Comment: That kind of question might be a good question all on its own, although it may have already been answered. Probably search for something like: What is the geometric meaning of localization?

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out

Comment: do you reckon this is the coordinate ring of the intersection of these two curves? Because I was thinking that unless the curves have a common component they should intersect in a set of points.

Comment: But the curves *do* have a common component. I mean they're the same curve to start with.